# Kill specific screen

Tags: zsh

```
#!/usr/bin/env zsh

doit() {
    if [[ "$1" = 'stop' ]]; then
        for loc in $(cat all-doc); do
            if screen -list | grep -q My-$loc; then
                pkill -f My-$loc;
            fi
        done
    else
        echo "Option: ERROR..."
    fi
}

case "$1" in
    start)
           start;
           ;;
    stop)
           doit "$1";
           ;;
    restart)
           restart;
           ;;
    *)
           echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart}"
           exit 1
           ;;
esac

exit 0
```

> ./shellscript.sh stop

I changed my question for reasones.
What's wrong? I need to kill specific screen that call from all-doc file, for example i have "test" in all-doc so that screen to be kill is "My-test".

Comment: In your switch/case you call `doit` whitout parameters, so `$1` in the context of the function isn't equal to stop. It seems to me you should just remove the if/else from your function since you use the switch/case to validate the parameter passed to the script

Comment: @Aaron i need to check if $1 match with "stop" word string.

Comment: Doesn't your switch/case do that? `case "$1" in [...] stop) doit; [...]` will call `doit` only when `$1` is "stop". Also `$1` depends on the context : inside a function it's not the first parameter your program was called with bur rather the first parameter the function was called with (and there's no such parameter when you call `doit`)

Comment: If you don't want to remove the if/else, you can change your `doit` call into `doit 'stop'`, or `doit "$1"`, but whichever of those two you use you'll never pass in your if's else block (`doit "$1"` could reach the else if if was called from somewhere else than the 'stop' branch of the switch/case that checks the value of `$1`)

Comment: @Aaron i have two more if for check "start" and "restart" too in 'doit' function: ```if [[ "$1" = 'start' ]]; then.....if [[ "$1" = 'restart' ]]; then```

Comment: That sounds redundant. Anyway did you get why you encounter your error?

Comment: I need somthing like ```./shellscript.sh "function" "start"``` i have 3 function "doit" "donot" "whatever"

Comment: ```That sounds redundant. Anyway did you get why you encounter your error?```     Not sure.

Comment: You're calling `doit` without parameters, and when you're inside a function `$1` doesn't refer to the script's parameter anymore but to the parameters you called the function with. You could use `doit "$1"` instead of your current `doit` in order to pass the script's (first) parameter to the function

Comment: @Aaron Ok i did it , and error gone now but that screen i need to close didnt closed.

Comment: @Auron can you help about this new issue ? I changed my code and question.

Comment: You'd better create a new question so it gets more attention and leave your old question as is. I'm not familiar with `screen` , can't really help you there. Maybe debug your script with `bash -x` to see if the variables are set to the values you expect and which condition pass or not?